# Representing prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove mathematically that $6n+1$ is a prime number if n is any other prime number.

E.g. if I put $n=2$ I get 13 which is another prime number.

Comment: You probably mean "that $6n+1$ is prime", because you certainly can't represent e.g. 23 by that

Comment: False. You should know that $6n+1$ is never divisible by $2$ or $3$. But what about divisibility by $5$? Starting looking for a counterexample (or scroll further down) there!

Comment: If we test whether 6n + 1 is a prime or not, does n being prime actually make it significantly more likely that 6n + 1 would be prime?

Answer (score 5):

Note that $6 \cdot 12641124929 + 1 = 75846749575$ is not prime.

(I'll leave it to you to verify that this actually answers the question asked.)

Comment: It actually already fails for 19...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: I never said this was a minimal counterexample.

Comment: Indeed, but how did you come up with 12641124929 of all primes?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Didn't want to give away a simple answer; knew one digit of the number I was looking for; found something appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

This one is wrong, taking the eigth prime (19) we have 
$$19\cdot 6+1=114+1=115 = 5 \cdot 23$$
It fails for the 10th prime too (29). There we have
$$29 \cdot 6 +1 = 174+1=175= 7\cdot 5^2$$

Here is a table calculated with *Mathematica* for the first 100 primes:

> Table[PrimeQ[6*Prime[n]+1],{n,1,100}]

and the out is:

True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, False, False,
True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True,
False, True, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False,
True, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False,
True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True,
False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True,
False, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, False,
True, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False,
False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, False,
False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False

Note that $6n+1$ is prime when $n$ is prime would imply that there is no prime ending on a $9$ as the last digit would be 
$$6 \cdot 9 +1 \equiv 5 \operatorname{mod} 10$$
And this always have the divisor $5$.

Comment: Or shorter: It fails for any $n$ ending with 9, but failure is not restricted to these (e.g. it also fails for any prime ending with 9 in base 15)

Answer (score 0):

This is false. For example $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$ and $11$ cannot be represented in this way.

Comment: I suspect their intended claim was that $6n+1$ is prime for $n$ prime

Comment: yes thats what i meant

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Maybe. For the moment I'll answer the question asked.

Comment: @user2170497: Then edit your question to say that.